# Cadastro utilizando struct

Tags: c

Preciso criar um algoritmo de cadastro que cadastra, exibe e exclui. não consegui na parte de excluir. algum me da uma luz plsss!!!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<string.h>


int i=0,cdg, cont=0;

typedef struct {
                char nome[30];
                char rua [50];
                int numero;      
                }cadastro;


cadastro cadastrar()
{    
   cadastro c;
    printf ("\n Sistema Cadastrar Clientes ");
    printf ("\n Informe o nome:  ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", c.nome);
    printf (" Informe a rua:     ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",c.rua);
    printf (" Informe o numero:  ");
    scanf("%d",&c.numero);
    cont++;

    return c;
}

 exibir (cadastro cad[])
{ 
  printf("\n Exibição de cadastro    \n");
    for (int j=0;j<cont;j++){
          printf("\n     CODIGO:   %d", i);
          printf("\nNome ...........: %s", cad[j].nome);
          printf("\nRua ...........: %s", cad[j].rua);
          printf("\nNumero ...........: %d\n", cad[j].numero);

    }
        system ("pause >>NULL");
}


 excluir(cadastro cad[])
{   int opc,i,j;
    printf ("Informe o codigo que deseja excluir: ");
    scanf("%d",&opc);
    for (i=0;i=opc;i++){
        for (j=0;j=!'/0';j++){
           cadastro cad [j].nome = "";
           cad[j].rua = ' ';
           cad[j].numero = 0;
    }
}

}


int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese")
    system("cls");
      int opc;
      cadastro cad[500];



    do{
    system("cls");
    printf ("\n SISTEMA CADASTRO \n\n 1 - CADASTRAR\n 2 - EXIBIR      **** 5 p/ SAIR");
    printf ("\n\n Digite a opção:     ");
    scanf ("%d", &opc);
    system("cls");
   switch(opc){
    case 1 : cad [i]=cadastrar();
             i++;
             break;
    case 2 : exibir(cad);
             break; 
    case 3: excluir (cad)         
            break; 
   printf ("\n SISTEMA CADASTRO \n\n 1 - CADASTRAR\n 2 - EXIBIR      **** 5 p/ SAIR");
}while(opc != 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A exclusão é feita diminuindo o tamanho que está a considerar no momento, no seu caso dado pela variável `cont`, e puxando todos os elementos a partir do removido uma casa para trás, deixando assim a ultima casa "vazia".

Visualmente algo deste género:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f] - Tamanho 6
```

Removendo o `c`:

```
[a, b, d, e, f,  ] - Tamanho 5
```

O que você faz é começar no `c`, e colocar o `d` no `c`, depois coloca o `e` no `d`, e assim sucessivamente. No fim pode optar por limpar o ultimo ou não, mas tipicamente não fará diferença, dependendo do seu algoritmo de inserção.

Código C ajustado ao seu programa:

```
void excluir(cadastro cad[])
{   
    int opc,i;
    printf ("Informe o codigo que deseja excluir: ");
    scanf("%d",&opc);
    for (i=opc;i < cont - 1;i++){ //começa no a remover e vai até ao penúltimo
        cad[i] = cad[i + 1]; //coloca o da frente no corrente
    }

    cont--; //diminuir o tamanho que está a ser considerado
}
```

Note que optei por não "limpar" o ultimo registo porque não fará diferença, a menos que o seu algoritmo faça algo que não deva. Se adicionar corretamente no fim, a próxima adição irá substituir os valores que lá ficaram.

Mas se o quiser fazer basta colocar antes do `cont--` o seguinte:

```
cad[cont - 1].nome[0] = '\0';
cad[cont - 1].rua[0] = '\0';
cad[cont - 1].numero = 0;
```